# Simplify this expression of ordinal numbers: $(ω+1) ω²$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $ω$ be the ordinal of the natural numbers. Simplify $(ω+1) ω²$

Comment: This question is on hold, why? So that Mario Carneiro is the only one that can answer it? Interestingly he voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of ordinal multiplication ($\delta$ is a limit ordinal, $\beta$ is any ordinal):

$$\alpha\cdot0=0\qquad\alpha\cdot(\beta+1)=(\alpha\cdot\beta)+\alpha\qquad\alpha\cdot\delta=\sup_{\beta<\delta}\alpha\cdot\beta$$

By transfinite induction, let's prove that $(\omega+1)\cdot\alpha=\omega\cdot\alpha+1$ if $\alpha$ is a successor and $(\omega+1)\cdot\alpha=\omega\cdot\alpha$ otherwise.

$$(\omega+1)\cdot0=0=\omega\cdot0$$

\begin{align}
(\omega+1)\cdot(\beta+1)&=(\omega+1)\cdot\beta+(\omega+1)\\
&=((\omega+1)\cdot\beta+\omega)+1\\
&=((\omega\cdot\beta+1)+\omega)+1\\
&=(\omega\cdot\beta+\omega)+1\\
&=\omega\cdot(\beta+1)+1\end{align}

If $\beta$ is not a successor, then skip the third step above. (Note that $(\alpha+1)+\omega=\alpha+\omega$ was used; this is because the supremum of $\alpha+1+n$ for $n<\omega$ is $\alpha+\omega$.) Finally, for limit ordinals, the supremum of $\omega\cdot\beta+1$ for $\beta<\delta$ is $\omega\cdot\delta$, so we are done. Plugging in $\alpha=\omega^2$ gives $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega^2=\omega\cdot\omega^2=\omega^3$.

---

Alternatively, we can give an order isomorphism $f$ between the set $\omega^2\times(\omega+1)=\{(\omega a+b,c):a,b\in\omega,c\in\omega+1\}$ under dictionary order, with the first factor as the most significant position, and $\omega^3$.

If $c=\omega$, then let $f(\omega a+b,\omega)=\omega^2a+\omega (b+1)$. Else if $b=0$, then let $f(\omega a,c)=\omega^2a+c$. Otherwise let $f(\omega a+b,c)=\omega^2 a+\omega b+(c+1)$.

Comment: @Asaf I don't follow. $\omega^2$ is a limit ordinal, and that's all that matters. I didn't prove that $\omega\cdot\omega^2=\omega^3$ - you may need to use the specifics of $\omega^2$ for that - but other than that there are no special properties of $\omega^2$ in use here. This same proof also shows that $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega_1=\omega\cdot\omega_1$: cofinality doesn't come in here.

Comment: @Asaf I'm still missing which step you doubt. Is it the claim that $\sup_{\beta<\delta}\omega\cdot\beta+1=\omega+\delta$?

Comment: It sounds like you want me to do a second-level induction or something on the limit step, and I don't get what you mean. And by 'doubt' I mean of course that you think the step is not well-justified, not that it is wrong.