# Ordinal multiplication

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I understand why $(\omega+1)\cdot2 = \omega\cdot2+1$ and why $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega = \omega^2$

What I am struggling with is something along the lines of:

$(\omega\cdot3+4)\cdot3$ which I think is = $\omega\cdot9+4$

And:

$(\omega\cdot3+4)(\omega\cdot3)$ which I think is = $\omega^2\cdot9$

Am I correct?

Comment: Could you explain how to evaluate them?

Comment: (w.3 + 4).3 = (w.3 + 4) + (w.3 + 4) + (w.3 + 4) = w.3 + (4 + w.3) + (4 + w.3) + 4 = w.3 + w.3 + w.3 + 4 = w.9 + 4 ??

Comment: Your first evaluation is correct; however the second one is not valid.

Comment: Thank you.

I was following [this explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764913/simplify-this-expression-of-ordinal-numbers-%cf%891-%cf%89%c2%b2) for (w + 1).w^2 and trying to extrapolate, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have evaluated $(\omega\cdot 3+4)\cdot 3$ correctly. However, $(\omega\cdot 3+4)\cdot(\omega\cdot 3)$ is not correctly evaluated. I do not know which step of your evaluation is incorrect, but I guess you think $(\omega\cdot 3)^2$ is $\omega^2\cdot 9$.

This is not true, however, as
$$(\omega\cdot 3)\cdot (\omega\cdot 3) = \omega\cdot (3\cdot\omega)\cdot 3 = \omega^2\cdot 3.$$
The core part of the evaluation is $3\cdot\omega=\omega$ that can be proven in the way of proving $3+\omega =\omega$ (and the linked question in your comment.)

We would think evaluating $(\omega\cdot 3+4)\cdot(\omega\cdot 3)$ is not too different from that of $(\omega\cdot 3)\cdot (\omega\cdot 3)$. The problem is, we have extra $+4$ and we cannot apply the distribution law in the case. 
However, the addition in the middle of the expression would disappear when adding $(\omega\cdot 3+4)$ many times, so we can guess the answer is $\omega^2\cdot 3$.

You can make our discussion concretely by following the steps of the proof you have linked; that is, use the transfinite induction for $\beta\le \omega\cdot 3$ to prove
$$(\omega\cdot 3+4)\cdot\beta = \begin{cases}
\omega\cdot (3\cdot\beta) &\text{if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal,} \\ \omega\cdot (3\cdot\beta) + 4 & \text{if $\beta$ is a successor ordinal.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you very much.

So would I right in saying then that something like (w⋅2+2)⋅(w⋅3) would = (w^2).3 ?

Comment: @Fraiku Yes. $\!$

Comment: Sorry, you are being so helpful I hope you don't mind if I ask you another question.  Given the lack of distributive law on the right, I am struggling to know where to start to tackle more complex multiplications such as: ((w^2).2)+(w.3+1))5   or ((w^2).2)+(w.3+1))(w.5)

Comment: @Fraiku The easiest strategy is evaluate $\alpha\cdot\beta$ for small $\beta$ and guess the pattern.

Comment: So ((w^2).2)+(w.3+1))2 = ((w^2).2)+(w.3+1)+((w^2).2)+(w.3+1) = ((w^2).2)+((w^2).2)+(w.3+1) = ((w^2).4)+w.3+1?

Comment: @Fraiku It seems right.

Comment: So for ((w^2).2)+(w.3+1))(w.5), following your original answer and the previously linked one, the answer I'm getting is ((w^3).w.5) but I'm really not sure.

Comment: @Fraiku You are correct; $\omega^2\cdot 2$ absorbs all $\omega\cdot 3+1$ and 2 in $\omega^2\cdot 2$ is absorbed by $\omega\cdot 5$.